# Error while connecting to mysql in .netcore 1.1 web api while running from docker

Tags: mysql, docker, .net-core

I am trying to dockerize a web api in dotnet core 1.1 with MySQL as back end. I added docker support for my project.

The **dockerfile** and **docker-compose.ci.build.yaml** ,**docker-compose.yml** and **docker-compose.override.yml** is as shown below. But i am getting an error like

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'UnableToConnectToHost'
>   ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused,,

**dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PDSController.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.ci.build.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-1.1
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./PDSController.sln && dotnet publish ./PDSController.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  pdscontroller:
    image: pdscontroller
    build:
      context: ./PDSController
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  pdscontroller:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
```

what changes do I have to make in these files , in order to connect to my database while running in docker. I am new to docker. Please help, thanks in advance. And also I am planning to push this api to AWS.